# How to connect and disconnect an openvpn connection in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, openvpn

How to run write a bash script to do a task after an `openvpn` connection as

```
#!/bin/bash
openvpn --config file.ovpn (step 1)
RUN THE TASK AFTER THE CONNECTION (step 2)
THEN DISCONNECT FROM THE OPENVPN (step 3)
```

My problem is how to move from the step 1 to step 2. I tried `up` and `daemon` options in `openvpn` to trigger step 2 in background, but in this case, we do not know when step 2 is finished to trigger step 3.

The problem is how to use `openvpn` as a regular command in a `bash` script to go to the next line when the connection is established.

Comment: `killall openvpn`

Comment: @GAD3R I edited the question to explain the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl start openvpn@vpnname # (step 1)
# RUN THE TASK AFTER THE CONNECTION (step 2)
sudo systemctl stop openvpn@vpnname # (step 3)
```

vpnname must be replaced with the name of a vpn connection configured at `/etc/openvpn/`. For example, `/etc/openvpn/vpnname.conf`

Comment: This is useful. Also for keeping exactly one --daemonized openvpn client prozess running/stopped in the background, for each available .conf / connection.
Furthermore, systemctl will trigger sudo if required.